___isPlatformVersionAtLeast is undefined symbols for architecture arm64
I developed a rust project. Recently the following error occurred when compile with cargo build:
          ld: warning: object file (/Users/allevo/repos/rustorama/target/debug/deps/libpsm-83eedad46edb0793.rlib[4](e4479bd7784abb10-aarch_aapcs64.o)) was built for newer 'macOS' version (15.1) than being linked (15.0)
          Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
            "___isPlatformVersionAtLeast", referenced from:
                -[CoreMLExecution predict:outputs:getOutputTensorDataFn:] in libort_sys-fdecb7f06102bc10.rlib[55](model.mm.o)
          ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The first line (the warning one) is repeated multiple times for different libraries.
The final error blocks me to compile correctly the project.
I tried to update my Mac to 15.1, update rust (10 1.82), update every package with brew, update xcode and macos package, and restart the mac but the error persists.
Why I got this error?
How I can fix it?
I would like to compile the code successfully.

So this symbol is supposed to come from LLVM's "compiler-rt" library, but this should never be a problem when compiling for the native platform. As it stands, we can't debug your issue until you provide a [mcve].
